# click on autocomplete entries

Tags: android, autocomplete

I created an autocomplete which has his entries coming from a database.
Further,I wanna click on this entries and query in the database for some data depending on what was selected,any idea of what method should I implement as a clickListener?

Until now my code was built like this one:

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/08/writing-your-own-autocompletetextview/

UPDATE:
A table in my database is like this:  ROUTE USER_ID.In my autocomplete I have displayed the ROUTE only(the column named ROUTE) and when I click route I wanna find out the USER_ID for that ROUTE.

Comment: You want to get the selected value from that List?

Comment: I've edited my question...with further details